# DataTables jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I cant seem to add datatables to my table.
Can you help me to find what i'm doing wrong?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

[It doesn´t have the datatables jquery plugin idk why, it has the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0iay.png)
this is the links and scripts im using now to try to see if works, i already used the connection in the official website and it didnt work either.
I tried to make a new html page and it worked but in this one it doesnt seem to work.
If you want to download files here is the link http://sendanywhe.re/Z1UV5OCM i dont know another way to send files.
The problem I identify and I think is that the bootstrap or another thing is blocking the datatables jquery plugin.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="au theme template">
    <meta name="author" content="Hau Nguyen">
    <meta name="keywords" content="au theme template">


    

    <!-- Title Page-->
    <title>Tables</title>

    <!-- Fontfaces CSS-->
    <link href="css/font-face.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome-4.7/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome-5/css/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="vendor/mdi-font/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap-4.1/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

    <!-- Vendor CSS-->
    <link href="vendor/animsition/animsition.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="vendor/wow/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="vendor/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">


    
    <!-- Main CSS-->
    <link href="css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    
    

</head>

<body class="animsition">
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <!-- HEADER MOBILE-->
        <header class="header-mobile d-block d-lg-none">
            <div class="header-mobile__bar">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="header-mobile-inner">
                        <a class="logo" href="index.html">
                            <img src="images/Logo-horiz.png" alt="CoolAdmin" />
                        </a>
                        <button class="hamburger hamburger--slider" type="button">
                            <span class="hamburger-box">
                                <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                            </span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <nav class="navbar-mobile">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <ul class="navbar-mobile__list list-unstyled">
                        <li class="has-sub">
                            <a class="js-arrow" href="index.php">
                                <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>Pagina Inicial</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="chart.php">
                                <i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i>Adicionar Itens</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="table.php">
                                <i class="fas fa-table"></i>Itens Atuais</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="form.html">
                                <i class="far fa-check-square"></i>Clientes</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="calendar.html">
                                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>Detalhe De Encomendas</a>
                        </li>
                        
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <!-- END HEADER MOBILE-->

        <!-- MENU SIDEBAR-->
        <aside class="menu-sidebar d-none d-lg-block">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/icon/logo.png" alt="Cool Admin" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-sidebar__content js-scrollbar1">
                <nav class="navbar-sidebar">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled navbar__list">
                        <li class="has-sub">
                            <a class="js-arrow" href="#">
                                <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>Pagina Principal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="chart.html">
                                <i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i>Charts</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="table.html">
                                <i class="fas fa-table"></i>Tables</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="form.html">
                                <i class="far fa-check-square"></i>Forms</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="calendar.html">
                                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>Calendar</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="map.html">
                                <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>Maps</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </aside>
        <!-- END MENU SIDEBAR-->

        <!-- PAGE CONTAINER-->
        <div class="page-container">
            <!-- HEADER DESKTOP-->
            <header class="header-desktop">
                <div class="section__content section__content--p30">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="header-wrap">
                            <form class="form-header" action="" method="POST">
                                
                            </form>
                            <div class="header-button">
                                <div class="account-wrap">
                                    <div class="account-item clearfix js-item-menu">
                                        <div class="image">
                                            <img src="images/icon/avatar-01.jpg" alt="John Doe" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="content">
                                            <a class="js-acc-btn" href="#">Admin</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="account-dropdown js-dropdown">
                                            <div class="info clearfix">
                                                <div class="image">
                                                    <a href="#">
                                                        <img src="images/icon/avatar-01.jpg" alt="John Doe" />
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="content">
                                                    <h5 class="name">
                                                        <a href="#">Admin</a>
                                                    </h5>
                                                    <span class="email">???</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            <div class="account-dropdown__footer">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-power"></i>Logout</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <!-- END HEADER DESKTOP-->

            <!-- MAIN CONTENT-->
            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="section__content section__content--p30">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row m-t-30">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="table-responsive ">
                                    <table id="example" class="table table-borderless table-striped table-earning">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Referência</th>
                                                <th>Nome</th>
                                                <th>Descrição Detalhada</th>
                                                <th class="text-right">Preço de Custo</th>
                                                <th>Margem/%</th>
                                                <th>Stock</th>
                                                <th>IVA</th>
                                                <th>Familia</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2018-09-29 05:57</td>
                                                <td>100398</td>
                                                <td>iPhone X 64Gb Grey</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">$999.00</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">1</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">$999.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2018-09-28 01:22</td>
                                                <td>100397</td>
                                                <td>Samsung S8 Black</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">$756.00</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">1</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">$756.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2018-09-27 02:12</td>
                                                <td>100396</td>
                                                <td>Game Console Controller</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">$22.00</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">2</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">$44.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2018-09-26 23:06</td>
                                                <td>100395</td>
                                                <td>iPhone X 256Gb Black</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">$1199.00</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">1</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">$1199.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2018-09-25 19:03</td>
                                                <td>100393</td>
                                                <td>USB 3.0 Cable</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">$10.00</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">3</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">$30.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2018-09-29 05:57</td>
                                                <td>100392</td>
                                                <td>Smartwatch 4.0 LTE Wifi</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">$199.00</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">6</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">$1494.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2018-09-24 19:10</td>
                                                <td>100391</td>
                                                <td>Camera C430W 4k</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">$699.00</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">1</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">$699.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2018-09-22 00:43</td>
                                                <td>100393</td>
                                                <td>USB 3.0 Cable</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">$10.00</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">3</td>
                                                <td class="text-right">$30.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                                
                        
                        <div class="row m-t-30">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <!-- DATA TABLE-->
                                <div class="table-responsive m-b-40">
                                    <table class="table table-borderless table-data3">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>date</th>
                                                <th>type</th>
                                                <th>description</th>
                                                <th>status</th>
                                                <th>price</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2018-09-29 05:57</td>
                                                <td>Mobile</td>
                                                <td>iPhone X 64Gb Grey</td>
                                                <td class="process">Processed</td>
                                                <td>$999.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2018-09-28 01:22</td>
                                                <td>Mobile</td>
                                                <td>Samsung S8 Black</td>
                                                <td class="process">Processed</td>
                                                <td>$756.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2018-09-27 02:12</td>
                                                <td>Game</td>
                                                <td>Game Console Controller</td>
                                                <td class="denied">Denied</td>
                                                <td>$22.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2018-09-26 23:06</td>
                                                <td>Mobile</td>
                                                <td>iPhone X 256Gb Black</td>
                                                <td class="denied">Denied</td>
                                                <td>$1199.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2018-09-25 19:03</td>
                                                <td>Accessories</td>
                                                <td>USB 3.0 Cable</td>
                                                <td class="process">Processed</td>
                                                <td>$10.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2018-09-29 05:57</td>
                                                <td>Accesories</td>
                                                <td>Smartwatch 4.0 LTE Wifi</td>
                                                <td class="denied">Denied</td>
                                                <td>$199.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2018-09-24 19:10</td>
                                                <td>Camera</td>
                                                <td>Camera C430W 4k</td>
                                                <td class="process">Processed</td>
                                                <td>$699.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2018-09-22 00:43</td>
                                                <td>Computer</td>
                                                <td>Macbook Pro Retina 2017</td>
                                                <td class="process">Processed</td>
                                                <td>$10.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <!-- END DATA TABLE-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="copyright">
                                    <p>Copyright © 2018 Colorlib. All rights reserved. Template by <a href="https://colorlib.com">Colorlib</a>.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Jquery JS-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS-->
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap-4.1/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap-4.1/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Vendor JS       -->
    <script src="vendor/slick/slick.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="vendor/wow/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/animsition/animsition.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="vendor/counter-up/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/counter-up/jquery.counterup.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="vendor/circle-progress/circle-progress.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/chartjs/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/select2/select2.min.js">
    </script>

    <!-- Main JS-->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
      var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    } );
    </script>

</body>

</html>
<!-- end document-->
```

Comment: When you say, "I cant seem to add datatables to my table." what exactly do you mean? Are there any errors in the browser console? From your browser console, can you verify that the script is definitely there? If you have any further detail, edit your question to include this information so that others can assist you better.

Comment: @CiaranGallagher it doesn't show any error it simply doesn't show anything of datatables jquery, i found out that the problem was that i was running the html file with xampp, but i still need to run with xampp because im gonna fill the table with information coming from database.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-earning">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Referência</th>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Descrição Detalhada</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Preço de Custo</th>
                    <th>Margem/%</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                    <th>IVA</th>
                    <th>Familia</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>2018-09-29 05:57</td>
                    <td>100398</td>
                    <td>iPhone X 64Gb Grey</td>
                    <td class="text-right">$999.00</td>
                    <td class="text-right">1</td>
                    <td class="text-right">$999.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2018-09-28 01:22</td>
                    <td>100397</td>
                    <td>Samsung S8 Black</td>
                    <td class="text-right">$756.00</td>
                    <td class="text-right">1</td>
                    <td class="text-right">$756.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2018-09-27 02:12</td>
                    <td>100396</td>
                    <td>Game Console Controller</td>
                    <td class="text-right">$22.00</td>
                    <td class="text-right">2</td>
                    <td class="text-right">$44.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2018-09-26 23:06</td>
                    <td>100395</td>
                    <td>iPhone X 256Gb Black</td>
                    <td class="text-right">$1199.00</td>
                    <td class="text-right">1</td>
                    <td class="text-right">$1199.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2018-09-25 19:03</td>
                    <td>100393</td>
                    <td>USB 3.0 Cable</td>
                    <td class="text-right">$10.00</td>
                    <td class="text-right">3</td>
                    <td class="text-right">$30.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2018-09-29 05:57</td>
                    <td>100392</td>
                    <td>Smartwatch 4.0 LTE Wifi</td>
                    <td class="text-right">$199.00</td>
                    <td class="text-right">6</td>
                    <td class="text-right">$1494.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2018-09-24 19:10</td>
                    <td>100391</td>
                    <td>Camera C430W 4k</td>
                    <td class="text-right">$699.00</td>
                    <td class="text-right">1</td>
                    <td class="text-right">$699.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2018-09-22 00:43</td>
                    <td>100393</td>
                    <td>USB 3.0 Cable</td>
                    <td class="text-right">$10.00</td>
                    <td class="text-right">3</td>
                    <td class="text-right">$30.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    
    <br><hr><br>
    
        <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-data3">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>date</th>
                    <th>type</th>
                    <th>description</th>
                    <th>status</th>
                    <th>price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>2018-09-29 05:57</td>
                    <td>Mobile</td>
                    <td>iPhone X 64Gb Grey</td>
                    <td>Processed</td>
                    <td>$999.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2018-09-28 01:22</td>
                    <td>Mobile</td>
                    <td>Samsung S8 Black</td>
                    <td>Processed</td>
                    <td>$756.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2018-09-27 02:12</td>
                    <td>Game</td>
                    <td>Game Console Controller</td>
                    <td>Denied</td>
                    <td>$22.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2018-09-26 23:06</td>
                    <td>Mobile</td>
                    <td>iPhone X 256Gb Black</td>
                    <td>Denied</td>
                    <td>$1199.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2018-09-25 19:03</td>
                    <td>Accessories</td>
                    <td>USB 3.0 Cable</td>
                    <td>Processed</td>
                    <td>$10.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2018-09-29 05:57</td>
                    <td>Accesories</td>
                    <td>Smartwatch 4.0 LTE Wifi</td>
                    <td>Denied</td>
                    <td>$199.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2018-09-24 19:10</td>
                    <td>Camera</td>
                    <td>Camera C430W 4k</td>
                    <td>Processed</td>
                    <td>$699.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2018-09-22 00:43</td>
                    <td>Computer</td>
                    <td>Macbook Pro Retina 2017</td>
                    <td>Processed</td>
                    <td>$10.00</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready( function () {
                $('.table-earning').DataTable();
    
                $('.table-data3').DataTable();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Brother you have to add same no of columns in "**thead**" as well as "**tbody**"
in your first table "**thead**" have 8 columns but "**tbody**" have only 6 columns so just add
"**td**" 2 times and you good to go

Comment: I did what you said to do still not working, then i thought like maybe the problem its because im running in xampp and it actually it is when i opened the .html file by myself instead of doing it with the server it worked.But i still need to make it work with xampp, do you know how I do it?

Comment: No i don't exact idea about it can u tell me what error u face.

Comment: It doesn't show anything of the datatables jquery plugin.

Comment: Its like if i didn't had the code to show the datatable jquery plugin.

Comment: im using bootstrap and other things in my project do you want me to send?

Comment: this is the download link http://sendanywhe.re/Z1UV5OCM idk how to send it from other way.

Answer (score 0):

i added a few JS and CSS CDN for datatables

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css"
/>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"
/>
```

does this solve the issue?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="description" content="au theme template" />
    <meta name="author" content="Hau Nguyen" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="au theme template" />

    <!-- Title Page-->
    <title>Tables</title>

    <!-- Fontfaces CSS-->
    <link href="css/font-face.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
    <link
      href="vendor/font-awesome-4.7/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      media="all"
    />
    <link
      href="vendor/font-awesome-5/css/fontawesome-all.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      media="all"
    />
    <link
      href="vendor/mdi-font/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      media="all"
    />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link
      href="vendor/bootstrap-4.1/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      media="all"
    />

    <!-- Vendor CSS-->
    <link
      href="vendor/animsition/animsition.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      media="all"
    />
    <link
      href="vendor/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      media="all"
    />
    <link href="vendor/wow/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
    <link
      href="vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      media="all"
    />
    <link href="vendor/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
    <link href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
    <link
      href="vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      media="all"
    />

    <!-- Main CSS-->
    <link href="css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link
      href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"
    />
  </head>

  <body class="animsition">
    <div class="page-wrapper">
      <!-- HEADER MOBILE-->
      <header class="header-mobile d-block d-lg-none">
        <div class="header-mobile__bar">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="header-mobile-inner">
              <a class="logo" href="index.html">
                <img src="images/Logo-horiz.png" alt="CoolAdmin" />
              </a>
              <button class="hamburger hamburger--slider" type="button">
                <span class="hamburger-box">
                  <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar-mobile">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="navbar-mobile__list list-unstyled">
              <li class="has-sub">
                <a class="js-arrow" href="index.php">
                  <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>Pagina Inicial</a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="chart.php">
                  <i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i>Adicionar Itens</a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="table.php">
                  <i class="fas fa-table"></i>Itens Atuais</a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="form.html">
                  <i class="far fa-check-square"></i>Clientes</a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="calendar.html">
                  <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>Detalhe De Encomendas</a
                >
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <!-- END HEADER MOBILE-->

      <!-- MENU SIDEBAR-->
      <aside class="menu-sidebar d-none d-lg-block">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="images/icon/logo.png" alt="Cool Admin" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-sidebar__content js-scrollbar1">
          <nav class="navbar-sidebar">
            <ul class="list-unstyled navbar__list">
              <li class="has-sub">
                <a class="js-arrow" href="#">
                  <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>Pagina Principal</a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="chart.html"> <i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i>Charts</a>
              </li>
              <li class="active">
                <a href="table.html"> <i class="fas fa-table"></i>Tables</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="form.html">
                  <i class="far fa-check-square"></i>Forms</a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="calendar.html">
                  <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>Calendar</a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="map.html">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>Maps</a
                >
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <!-- END MENU SIDEBAR-->

      <!-- PAGE CONTAINER-->
      <div class="page-container">
        <!-- HEADER DESKTOP-->
        <header class="header-desktop">
          <div class="section__content section__content--p30">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="header-wrap">
                <form class="form-header" action="" method="POST"></form>
                <div class="header-button">
                  <div class="account-wrap">
                    <div class="account-item clearfix js-item-menu">
                      <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/icon/avatar-01.jpg" alt="John Doe" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="content">
                        <a class="js-acc-btn" href="#">Admin</a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="account-dropdown js-dropdown">
                        <div class="info clearfix">
                          <div class="image">
                            <a href="#">
                              <img
                                src="images/icon/avatar-01.jpg"
                                alt="John Doe"
                              />
                            </a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="content">
                            <h5 class="name">
                              <a href="#">Admin</a>
                            </h5>
                            <span class="email">???</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="account-dropdown__footer">
                          <a href="#"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-power"></i>Logout</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
        <!-- END HEADER DESKTOP-->

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT-->
        <div class="main-content">
          <div class="section__content section__content--p30">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row m-t-30">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="table-responsive ">
                    <table
                      id="example"
                      class="table table-borderless table-striped table-earning"
                    >
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Referência</th>
                          <th>Nome</th>
                          <th>Descrição Detalhada</th>
                          <th class="text-right">Preço de Custo</th>
                          <th>Margem/%</th>
                          <th>Stock</th>
                          <th>IVA</th>
                          <th>Familia</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2018-09-29 05:57</td>
                          <td>100398</td>
                          <td>iPhone X 64Gb Grey</td>
                          <td class="text-right">$999.00</td>
                          <td class="text-right">1</td>
                          <td class="text-right">$999.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2018-09-28 01:22</td>
                          <td>100397</td>
                          <td>Samsung S8 Black</td>
                          <td class="text-right">$756.00</td>
                          <td class="text-right">1</td>
                          <td class="text-right">$756.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2018-09-27 02:12</td>
                          <td>100396</td>
                          <td>Game Console Controller</td>
                          <td class="text-right">$22.00</td>
                          <td class="text-right">2</td>
                          <td class="text-right">$44.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2018-09-26 23:06</td>
                          <td>100395</td>
                          <td>iPhone X 256Gb Black</td>
                          <td class="text-right">$1199.00</td>
                          <td class="text-right">1</td>
                          <td class="text-right">$1199.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2018-09-25 19:03</td>
                          <td>100393</td>
                          <td>USB 3.0 Cable</td>
                          <td class="text-right">$10.00</td>
                          <td class="text-right">3</td>
                          <td class="text-right">$30.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2018-09-29 05:57</td>
                          <td>100392</td>
                          <td>Smartwatch 4.0 LTE Wifi</td>
                          <td class="text-right">$199.00</td>
                          <td class="text-right">6</td>
                          <td class="text-right">$1494.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2018-09-24 19:10</td>
                          <td>100391</td>
                          <td>Camera C430W 4k</td>
                          <td class="text-right">$699.00</td>
                          <td class="text-right">1</td>
                          <td class="text-right">$699.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2018-09-22 00:43</td>
                          <td>100393</td>
                          <td>USB 3.0 Cable</td>
                          <td class="text-right">$10.00</td>
                          <td class="text-right">3</td>
                          <td class="text-right">$30.00</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row m-t-30">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <!-- DATA TABLE-->
                  <div class="table-responsive m-b-40">
                    <table class="table table-borderless table-data3">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>date</th>
                          <th>type</th>
                          <th>description</th>
                          <th>status</th>
                          <th>price</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2018-09-29 05:57</td>
                          <td>Mobile</td>
                          <td>iPhone X 64Gb Grey</td>
                          <td class="process">Processed</td>
                          <td>$999.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2018-09-28 01:22</td>
                          <td>Mobile</td>
                          <td>Samsung S8 Black</td>
                          <td class="process">Processed</td>
                          <td>$756.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2018-09-27 02:12</td>
                          <td>Game</td>
                          <td>Game Console Controller</td>
                          <td class="denied">Denied</td>
                          <td>$22.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2018-09-26 23:06</td>
                          <td>Mobile</td>
                          <td>iPhone X 256Gb Black</td>
                          <td class="denied">Denied</td>
                          <td>$1199.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2018-09-25 19:03</td>
                          <td>Accessories</td>
                          <td>USB 3.0 Cable</td>
                          <td class="process">Processed</td>
                          <td>$10.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2018-09-29 05:57</td>
                          <td>Accesories</td>
                          <td>Smartwatch 4.0 LTE Wifi</td>
                          <td class="denied">Denied</td>
                          <td>$199.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2018-09-24 19:10</td>
                          <td>Camera</td>
                          <td>Camera C430W 4k</td>
                          <td class="process">Processed</td>
                          <td>$699.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2018-09-22 00:43</td>
                          <td>Computer</td>
                          <td>Macbook Pro Retina 2017</td>
                          <td class="process">Processed</td>
                          <td>$10.00</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <!-- END DATA TABLE-->
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="copyright">
                    <p>
                      Copyright © 2018 Colorlib. All rights reserved. Template
                      by <a href="https://colorlib.com">Colorlib</a>.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Jquery JS-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS-->
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap-4.1/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap-4.1/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Vendor JS       -->
    <script src="vendor/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/wow/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/animsition/animsition.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/counter-up/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/counter-up/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/circle-progress/circle-progress.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/chartjs/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Main JS-->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $("#example").DataTable();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still not working and still the same. No errors shown

Comment: was this  https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4 not what you were trying to mimic?